# Uma única regex para duas opções diferentes

Tags: javascript, regex

Como eu posso usar o regex duas vezes tipo assim:

```
let A =  /^A2\d{8}.{26}\d{12}$ , ^A3\d{16}.{26}\d{15}$/;
```

Qual seria a forma de usar ele para `A2` e `A3` sem precisar usar o regex duas vezes, tipo:

```
let A =  /^A2\d{8}.{26}\d{12}$/;
let A1 = /^A3\d{16}.{26}\d{15}$/;
```

Aqui um exemplo:

```
A220180829Dinheiro                 1000000300767
A310180829Dinheiro                 2000000002600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só um detalhe, uma das regex que você usou:

```
let A1 = /^A3\d{16}.{26}\d{15}$/;
```

Não condiz com o texto de exemplo:

```
A220180829Dinheiro                 1000000300767
A310180829Dinheiro                 2000000002600
```

Pois depois de "A3" ela considera que tem 16 dígitos (`\d{16}`), mas o texto acima só possui 8. Além disso, no final da regex ela procura por 15 dígitos (`\d{15}`), mas o texto acima só possui 13 (então a regex acima não dará *match* na segunda linha do texto).

Sendo assim, vou considerar duas opções: que as regex estão corretas e o texto errado, ou vice-versa.

---

#### Considerando as regex e ignorando o texto de exemplo

Se quer uma única regex que considere as duas opções, use [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (considerando as regex que estão na pergunta). Ou seja, em vez de ter essas duas expressões:

```
let A =  /^A2\d{8}.{26}\d{12}$/;
let A1 = /^A3\d{16}.{26}\d{15}$/;
```

Eu junto elas em uma só:

```
let a2OUa3 = /^(A2\d{8}.{26}\d{12}|A3\d{16}.{26}\d{15})$/;
```

O caractere `|` significa "ou". Isso quer dizer que a regex acima considera a string pode ter "A2" (seguida de 8 dígitos, etc) **ou** "A3" (seguida de 16 dígitos, etc).

---

#### Considerando o texto de exemplo e ignorando a segunda regex

Agora se quer considerar o texto que você colocou na pergunta (com 8 dígitos depois de "A3", e não 16 como está na regex da pergunta), há outras opções.

Nesse caso, no início pode ser tanto "A2" quanto "A3", e o restante é igual, então uma alternativa é usar uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
let a2OUa3 = /^A[23]\d{8}.{26}\d{12}$/;
```

No caso, `[23]` significa "o dígito `2` **ou** o dígito `3`".

---

Você também poderia usar [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
let a2OUa3 = /^(A2|A3)\d{8}.{26}\d{12}$/;
```

`A2|A3` significa "A2 **ou** A3" (agrupado entre parênteses pois o `|` possui menor precedência).

Claro que outra opção seria:

```
let a2OUa3 = /^A(2|3)\d{8}.{26}\d{12}$/;
```

---

A diferença é que a classe de caracteres só pode ser usada quando as opções correspondem a apenas um caractere. Já a alternância pode ser usada para expressões de qualquer tamanho.

Ou seja:

- `(A2|A3)` significa "A2 ou A3"
- `[A2|A3]` significa "a letra `A`, ou o dígito `2`, ou o caractere `|`, ou a letra `A`, ou o dígito `3`" (somente um deles - vale notar que a letra `A` está redundante neste caso)

Comment: hkotsubo Na verdade aquele alí eu peguei como exemplo só para exemplificar mesmo, não que eles sejam iguais. Mas se for o caso de serem diferentes como faria?

Comment: @Lagaggio Se as opções são diferentes, use a segunda solução: `(A2|A3)` - ou de forma mais geral, `(opcao1|opcao2|opcao3|....)`. Se não for isso, por favor edite a pergunta

Comment: quero dizer se for algo assim: ```^A2\d{8}.{26}\d{12}$ e ^A3\d{10}.{12}\d{12}$```

Comment: @Lagaggio Se quer que seja A2 **e** A3 ao mesmo tempo, não dá, a regex pega um ou outro. Aliás, não tem como um texto corresponder a essas duas regex ao mesmo tempo, ou ele será A2, ou A3 (ou nenhum). Tem alguns exemplos de textos e o resultado que vc precisa? (coloque na pergunta)

Comment: @Lagaggio Atualizei a resposta, veja se é o que precisa...

Comment: Então se for seguir sua resposta  se eu precisasse que as duas estivessem corretas eu adicionaria o sinal de & no exemplo ```let a2OUa3 = /^(A2\d{8}.{26}\d{12}&A3\d{16}.{26}\d{15})$/;```, ou seria de outra forma?

Comment: @Lagaggio Como eu já disse, não tem como as 2 estarem corretas ao mesmo tempo. Ou a string começa com A2 ou com A3. Se vc quer uma única regex que pegue tanto A2 quanto A3, as que eu coloquei já fazem isso (elas pegam tanto as linhas que tem A2 quanto as que tem A3). Ou então eu não consegui entender o que vc precisa...

Comment: Não tem como ela validar as duas ao mesmo tempo então? Pq lá a condição vai só validar uma. Eu vou ter que criar uma regex para cada A1, A2 ou A3 que eu tiver?

Comment: @Lagaggio Ela valida tanto A2 quanto A3, veja: https://repl.it/repls/LinedFamiliarFossil - acho que o que me confundiu foi o "ao mesmo tempo", mas de qualquer forma, dá pra usar uma única regex que valida tanto A2 quanto A3 (que é o que coloquei na resposta)